# Laravel Storage, File not found

Tags: laravel-5, filesystems, move

In my public folder I have and uploads folder. I am trying to move a file into a sub folder.

```
Storage::move('uploads/myfile.gif', 'uploads/newfolder/myfile.gif');
```

However I get the errir, file not found at path: uploads/myfile.gif

Any ideas why the file is not being found? I have set the permissions to 777 for the uploads folder and the files.

Answer (score 0):

In **filesystems.php** add a driver

```
'uploads' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root'   => public_path(),
],
```

Then

Storage::disk('public')->move('uploads/myfile.gif', 'uploads/newfolder/newfile.gif');